# Best way to finish off this stair trim

Tags: stairs, trim

Looking for ideas please on the best way to complete this trim.
Do I run the 1/4 round to the floor and trim the baseboard to fit, or run the baseboard to the stairs and [somehow] match the 1/4 round to baseboard?
Or other options>?

[image]
[image]

Comment: there is no *best way* unless you define what that means

Comment: have you thought of using a triangular piece, attached to the end of the stair stringer? ... triangular cross section when viewed from top, looking straight down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill the gap with a plug at the space between the stair stringer and wall (2nd photo: where the floor molding disappears). Or cap the beveled end of the stair stringer with 3/4" pine with the stringers profile.

If that gap is closed the floor molding will butt against it. Than the quarter round can be terminated with a face bevel right equal with the stringer.

The gap has to be covered in order to have an flat (90 degree) surface to cut the molding's to.